# How can I solve $z^n = z^\ast$

Tags: complex-numbers

Where z is a complex number in the form $z = a+bi$, and $n\in \mathbb{R}$. I was capable of solving this for $z^2 = z^\ast$ by expanding both sides. But I was wondering if there was a way to solve for all n.

The answers I got for $z^2 = z^\ast$ were:
$$ z= 0$$
$$ z= 1$$
$$ z= -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$$
$$ z= -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$$

Comment: Try moving to the polar representation of a complex number.

Comment: Hint: note that either $z=0$ or $|z|=1$, and for $|z|=1$ we have $z^*=z^{-1}$.